# Set rows` color in tr-ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to set row colors for my [tr-ng-grid](https://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid) table.

I have no clue how to start with it. Here is my table:

```
<table tr-ng-grid="" items="vm.addresses"></table>
```

Address model has property count. All I want to do it some condition like:

```
row.color = address.count > 5 ? ? red : blue
```

Is is even possbile? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

should be ok

```
<table tr-ng-grid items='vm.addresses'>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-class="gridItem.count > 5 ? 'red-class' : 'blue-class'"></tr>
            </tbody>
    </table>
```